# How to get a list of modules implementing hooks?

Tags: hooks

Is it possible to get a list of defined hooks for debugging purposes?

I have implemented `mymodule_datalayer_meta()` for `datalayer`'s `hook_datalayer_meta()`. However, as far as I can tell, it's not firing. I'd like to look up a list of hooks that modules implement so I can see if my module is actually implementing it or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [module_implements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_implements/7) function

> Determines which modules are implementing a hook.

Use this function in the devel/php form, for example.

```
dpm(module_implements('THE_HOOK'));
```

This way you can see easily if your module implements 'THE_HOOK'.

Answer (score 4):

If you've got access to drush (and you want to use it), you can use `drush hook menu` (this is obviously for `hook_menu`)

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are not stored in the database, but they are actually cached into the table `cache_bootstrap`. See [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/155903/17632) for a clue on how to see a list of cached hooks.

Comment: I've had a look at it, my cached hooks table appears to be empty: `$> drush @site sqlc -A

MariaDB [site_db]> select * FROM cache_bootstrap;

Empty set (0.00 sec)
`

Comment: Something is wrong. This table contains some basic records in all Drupal installations (like cached variables). I'm not too savvy about this, but perhaps you need to clear the cache so that everything is rebuilt? Do you have the right database? Perhaps your site is not using cache?? (not a good idea - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28340/completely-turn-off-caching-for-drupal-7)

Comment: are you sure this cache table isn't cleared after a cache clear?

Comment: The cache is cleared, but from what I'm seeing right now (I'm testing this as we speak) there are several records in that table that are rebuilt with every cache clearing, including system_list, variables,  boostrap_modules, etc

Comment: Not sure what's going on, site seems to work okay :S

Answer (score 0):

The PhpStorm IDE can also tell you where a hook is used (= implemented).

- Click on the arrow up left to your hook implementation to go to the hook documentation in an .api file and there you can click on the arrow down to see all implementations of it.